# can i get the image url in web page content and show into chrome extension?

Tags: javascript

I am an creating chrome extension using html css3 and Javascript now the problem is that can i get image url on mouseover any website and show the image into my chrome extension. below the code given manifest file. I don't find any function use content script to get the image Url

**Manifest File**

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "React Extention",
  "author": "Muhammad Yousuf",
  "version": "1.0.1",
  "options_page": "index.html",
  "description": "Replace new tab screen with GitHub trending projects.",
  "web_accessible_resources": ["index.html"],
  "incognito": "split",
  "icons": {
    "16": "logo.png",
    "48": "logo.png",
    "128": "logo.png"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.dawn.com/*"],
      "js": ["content-script.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Extention"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "presistent":false
  },
 "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'sha256-GgRxrVOKNdB4LrRsVPDSbzvfdV4UqglmviH9GoBJ5jk='; object-src 'self'",

  "permissions": ["tabs", "http://*/*", "storage"]
}
```

Comment: Yes you can fetch src of img but you need to check first that mouseover element is a <img> tag then you can fetch its src easily

Comment: Can you Please Show Some Code How to Pick Image Source

Comment: i've posted my code in answer plz check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I've detected hovered element first then I've checked its tag name

```
 var hovered_elemnet = (window.event) ? window.event.srcElement : e.target;
        console.log("hovered_elemne",hovered_elemnet.tagName)
        if (hovered_elemnet.tagName == "IMG") {
            console.log("src--",clickedElement.src);
        }
```

Comment: your welcome @MuhammadYousuf it would be great if you upvote my effort too :)

Comment: Sure But Problem is that I can't Vote Because my Profile is new and less than 15 reputation

Comment: Sure @the_ultimate_developer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.onmouseover = (event)=>{
    if (event.target.nodeName === 'IMG') {
      console.log(event.target.src)
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks to answer my question I have Already solve the Problem. But once again thankyou so much.

Comment: @MuhammadYousuf if you've answered your own question, you're free to post the answer yourself too so people can use it in future.